# How do you count the common 1's in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data for example:

| A | B | C | Class_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | B_C |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | A_B_C |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | C |

How do you obtain (classified label column) this and count the common ones and display that as well using pandas dataframe?

Comment: So in input data are no `Class_label` column, right? Is possible add input and expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for add new columns by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names for labels and `sum` for count `1`, but only numeric columns selected by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
df = df.assign(classifiedlabel = df1.dot(df1.columns + '_').str[:-1],
               countones = df1.sum(axis=1))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D classifiedlabel  countones
0  0  1  0  1             B_D          2
1  1  1  0  1           A_B_D          3
2  0  0  1  0               C          1
3  0  1  1  0             B_C          2
```

If column `classifiedlabel` exist simpliest is use `sum` only:

```
df["countones"] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D classifiedlabel  countones
0  0  1  0  1             B_D          2
1  1  1  0  1           A_B_D          3
2  0  0  1  0               C          1
3  0  1  1  0             B_C          2
```

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str', I am facing type error

Comment: @srinivasmuralidharan - Is there `classifiedlabel` before my solution or not?

Comment: @srinivasmuralidharan - My solution add both columns, need only one column?

Comment: It need both the columns.

Comment: @srinivasmuralidharan - So in input data are only columns filled by `0, 1` ?

Comment: @srinivasmuralidharan - added solution to answer - now is using `df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)`  in `df = df.assign(classifiedlabel = df1.dot(df1.columns + '_').str[:-1], countones = df1.sum(axis=1))`

Answer (score 1):

If values are 1/0 then you can use:

```
(
    df.assign(
        count=df._get_numeric_data().sum(axis=1)
    )
)
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C  D classifiedlabel  count
0  0  1  0  1             B_D      2
1  1  1  0  1           A_B_D      3
2  0  0  1  0               C      1
3  0  1  1  0             B_C      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["number_of_ones"] = (df == 1).astype(int).sum(axis=1)

print(df)

        A   B   C   D   classifiedlabel  number_of_ones
    0   0   1   0   1       B_D               2
    1   1   1   0   1      A_B_D              3
    2   0   0   1   0        C                1
    3   0   1   1   0       B_C               2
```